# Initialisng A Variable In A C++ Class Used In A Union?

Tags: c++, class, stl, unions

I am working on an application which in my opinion is rather poorly designed but that's another issue. There is a simple class in that app that I need to add a variable to. In this case I would like to add a STL stack to the class. Should be simple except that elsewhere the same class is used within a union and the compiler then complains that the class has a copy constructor. If I remove my added variable it compiles fine. My first thought was to add the stack as a pointer and then initialise it in the constructor but then the compiler complains that the class has a non trivial constructor.

My second (not ideal) thought was to add it as a pointer and initialise it outside the class. I know this isn't a good solution but I am up against some poorly designed code here which I cannot rewrite. However, this won't work because where I would need to initialise it, I cannot know if it has already been initialised or not. I cannot initialise the pointer in the class to NULL as even just doing that makes the compiler complain that the class now has a non-trivial constructor.

I guess my question is two-fold. Is there a way of adding a STL stack to a class that is used in a union? If not, is there a way of initialising a pointer to NULL in a class that is used in a union?

The class and union look something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        std::stack<short> Index; // ideally what I wanted
}

union
{
    int nNum;
    MyClass myclass;
} u;
```

Please note: I cannot change the union. I accept that I cannot do what I was thinking. Is there any alternative no matter how silly it might sound. I cannot change the union or redesign the app as much as I would like to. This is the problem when you work on large apps that were first written around 18 years ago.

Comment: Don't use unions. Just my advice.

Comment: As already stated I cannot change that code. It isn't mine and has been there for a long time. I cannot change it.

Comment: It's a sad thing that you can't rewrite it. Nevertheless, I keep my advice, because I consider it correct. That you can't do something doesn't mean that that is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the union as

```
union
{
    int nNum;
    MyClass * myclass;
} u;
```

This has the added benefit that int and pointer are the same size and it compiles.

Also, your example won't compile.  It's missing ';' at the end of the class.

Comment: I cannot alter the union. The code wasn't intended to compile, it was just for reference hence why I stated "something like". Thanks though.

Comment: Ahh, it wasn't entirely clear if you meant that literally as "I can't change anything about that union" or if you just couldn't stop using unions

Answer (score 0):

The answer for both questions is NO for C++03.
Since

### 9.5 Unions [class.union]

`1

...

 An object of a class with a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor
can an array of such objects. If a union contains a static data member, or a member of reference type,
the program is ill-formed.`
You still can add constructor to the union that will init pointer instead of class ctor.

In C++11 however you can provide your own constructors for union, that should implement correct way to copy classes with non trivial constructors.

### 9.5 Unions [class.union]

`2 A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. If a union contains a non-static data member of reference type the program is ill-formed. At most one non-static data member of a union may have a brace-or-equal-initializer. [Note: If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be
user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. — end note ]`

You may also be interested in a following article
http://cpp11standard.blogspot.com/2012/11/c11-standard-explained-1-unrestricted.html